# Assistance needed for cross-referencing tables on mysql/PHP back-end with AngularJS & Ionic

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, ionic-framework

As of right now I am making a call to the bookings API for a user with the id of "1001" this returns a JSON object with tons of keys and values.. As you guys can see from my `forEach` and `ng-repeat` I am grabbing the `arrival_date` and printing that on my `bookings.html view` That works great! However here is where it gets tricky for me as I am not very well versed in PHP, mysql and back-end stuff.

Aside from the arrival_date I need to get the actual first and last name of the customer.. It's my understanding that I need to do a **cross-reference** from the **bookings** table to the **customers** table which holds the `customer_id` but the **users** table is the one holding the customers first and last names! Not sure how I can do that.. The customers_id is '130' when I do on ng-repeat `{{booking.customer_id}}` I only get the number of the customer '130' and I know is because their actual info is not in that bookings table but in the customers table.

Forgive me if I make no sense but that exactly do I need to do to make this cross reference? Is this a Back-End PHP job or can I do this within Angular?

I've seen lots of examples on here and all over google. However I am curious as to if I do this on my PHP file where we have some DB queries happening and if I do it there.. do I have to make a brand new call to an other API??

Any feedback, suggestions or resources would be greatly appreciate it. Thank you so much in advance and have a good weekend all!

***bookingService.js***

```
angular.module('starter')
.service("BookingsService", function($http, $q) {

  var self = this;

  self.bookings = [];

  self.getBookings = function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.get("http://localhost/apiv2/bookings/1001")
        .success(function success (data) {
          console.log(data);

          var bookingData = data.forEach(function(trip) {
            self.bookings.push({
              arrival_date: trip.arrival_date
            });
          })

          self.bookings = data;
          deferred.resolve(true);

        })
        .error(function error (smg) {
          console.error(msg);
          deferred.reject(false);
        })

        return deferred.promise;
      };
```

***BookingsController.js***

```
 angular.module('starter')
 .controller("BookingsCtrl", function($scope, BookingsService) {

  $scope.today = [];
  $scope.test = 'scope test';

    BookingsService.getBookings().then(function success (data) {
      console.log("Success!");
      console.log(data);
      if(data){
        $scope.today = BookingsService.bookings;

      }

}, function error (data) {
  console.log("Error!")
```

bookings.html - view

```
<ion-view view-title="Your Bookings">
  <ion-content>
    <h3>Your Bookings</h3>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="booking in today">

           <ion-list> 
           <ion-item>

            <h4>
            Passenger: {{booking.customer_id}} 
            Address:{{booking.arrival_address}}
            </h4>

           </ion-item>
           </ion-list> 

      </ion-item>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: I am sorry Drew but I have no idea what that means. Was this intended for me?

Comment: Drew, Ah! thank you.. Sorry about that. This is a project I am working with some friends and its not live.. it's on our local server only. Is there any other info I could provide that could help?

Comment: let me get caught up and get back to you

Comment: I appreciate that! thanks